# Trouble creating a class representing safely-ORrable flags

Tags: c++, static

I'm trying to create a small set of classes implementing a "safe flag" pattern, which would allow only predefined values to be OR-ed together. I've came up with something like that:

```
class MyClass;

class CreateFlag
{
friend class MyClass;

private:
    int value;

    CreateFlag(int newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }

public:
    CreateFlag operator | (const CreateFlag & right) const
    {
        int newValue = value | right.value;
        return CreateFlag(newValue);
    }

    CreateFlag(const CreateFlag && flag)
    {
            value = flag.value;
    }

    CreateFlag(const CreateFlag & flag)
    {
        value = flag.value;
    }

    static const CreateFlag Flag1;
    static const CreateFlag Flag2;
    static const CreateFlag Flag4;
};

const CreateFlag CreateFlag::Flag1 = CreateFlag(1);
const CreateFlag CreateFlag::Flag2 = CreateFlag(2);
const CreateFlag CreateFlag::Flag4 = CreateFlag(4);

class MyClass
{
public:
    static void DisplayFlag(CreateFlag flag)
    {
        printf("Flag value: %d\n", flag.value);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv)
{
    MyClass::DisplayFlag(CreateFlag::Flag1 | CreateFlag::Flag2);

    getchar();
}
```

The problem is, that CreateFlag has a private ctor (what is intentional), so there is no way to specify the values of CreateFlag's static fields and the above code does not compile.

A way to bypass this restriction is to change static fields into static methods returning an instance of CreateFlag, but that's a dirty solution, as you would have to call the metod like:

```
MyClass::DisplayFlag(CreateFlag::Flag1() | CreateFlag::Flag2());
```

Is there a direct solution? If it changes anything, the flag definitions may be as well moved to the MyClass class.

I know also, that C++11 supports in-place initialization of static fields, but unfortunatelly VC++10 doesn't support this construct yet...

**Edit** I've modified the code, such that anyone can copy it and use, it compiles now and works as intended to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code doesn't compile, but I think that it's not compiling for reasons beyond what you're expecting.  Specifically, the compile error is in this line:

```
MyClass::DisplayFlag(CreateFlag::Flag1 | CreateFlag::Flag2);
```

The reason is that `DisplayFlag` takes its `CreateFlag` argument by value, and you've marked the copy constructor private.

If you're trying to ensure that people can't OR together invalid values, I don't think you need the copy constructor to be private.  Making copies of `CreateFlag`s that you know are valid doesn't allow clients to do anything that they previously couldn't do.  If you omit the definition of the copy constructor and just let C++'s default copy support work for you, you should be just fine.

The lines that you've indicated as causing the error don't seem to cause any problems.  **[It compiles just fine](http://ideone.com/AavX0)** once you remove the copy constructor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh poor me. I've corrected that mistake, but just after modifying the whole PoC, so I haven't noticed, that it actually works. Does it mean, that static field initializator has the same scope access as the class, which field is being initialized?

Comment: @Spook- I believe so, as it's logically part of the class.